# How to force printf to output [-]inf or [-]infinity on Windows?

Tags: windows, gcc, printf, mingw, c99

C99 standard says:

> A double argument representing an infinity is converted in one of the
>   styles [-]inf or [-]infinity -- which style is implemented is
>   implementation-defined. (p.278 section 7.19.6.1)

Unfortunately on Windows:

```
printf("%f\n", 1.0f/0.0f)
```

produces: 1.#INF00

This is a problem because some applications expect C standard compliant strings as input (also C#'s Double.Parse works for "Infinity" but not for "1.#INF00", curiously "infinity" is not ok either at least when I tried it with Mono).

My question is how do I force printf under Windows to output "inf" or "infinity" instead of 1.#INF00 ?

(I am compiling with MinGW gcc 4.8.2)

Comment: It seems that it doesn't have to do with the OS but with the compiler, i.e. `gcc` on windows should work as it does on linux for example.

Comment: Refer to [printf Type Field Characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx). There's a table that shows the formats for infinite, indefinite, and NAN; it doesn't mention any way to modify this. Note that MSVC only supports C89, not C99. @iharob, MinGW links with msvcrt.dll, so this is really dependent on the version of the CRT that's distributed with Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose between the MSVC (default) and mingw version of the printf-functions.
Just define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO like this, and the output should be C99 compliant:

```
#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1
```

Some documentation [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/printf%20and%20scanf%20family/) and [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/gnu%20printf/).

Comment: you need to include it before including stdio.h