# Long double is printed incorrectly in CodeBlocks using MinGW/long double

Tags: c, cygwin, mingw, codeblocks, mingw-w64

The problem:

My code work's fine using Cygwin (long double is printed like having 16 bytes of memory, and the min, and max values are OK), but using MinGW the CodeBlocks say long double have 12 bytes of memory (if I modify the code to show the size in int instead long double, in long double is -2,000000), and the min and max values it's printed like -0,000000 both.

Codeblocks version: 20.03.
MinGW-W64 project (version 8.1.0, 32/64 bit, SEH).

I tried with the prompt but, is the same thing!

I saw in a post that this problem is generated by Windows, but if it works with Cygwin, then there is a solution that maybe someone somewhere knows...

Observation:

I can use Cygwin, but Portuguese has so many accented words, and I use them to name my directories, so when I use Cygwin the things are complicated, and I don't know how can I include some libs like conio.h correctly, and the MinGW has included libs like conio.h so I prefer to learn how to resolve this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
// Declaration of variables
long double min, max, size;

// Size
size = sizeof(long double);

// Min and Max
min = pow(2, (sizeof(long double)*8))*(-1);
max = pow(2, (sizeof(long double)*8));

// Print of results
printf("Size of long double: %Lf\n", size);
printf("Min of long double: %Lf\n", min);
printf("Max of long double: %Lf\n", max);

// end of main
return(0);
}
```

In mingw:
[image]

In cygwin:
[image]

Comment: are you sure to use the 64bit version ? Long Double are 12 bytes long also on cygwin 32bit

Comment: I've compiled that code in several compilers. Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 saying long double's size is 8 (in both x32 and x64 mode, source is C++), gcc 10.2 x64 and clang 11.01.1 x64 saying it's size is 16 (both C and C++). Looks that different compilers implement long double different. But mingw case is clearly erroneous - size cannot be negative. Can you add `size_t sizeLD = sizeof(long double);` and check it's value in the debugger?

Comment: @matzeri - Yes, I have sure, I download the version 20.03 of codeblocks that have included the mingw64...

Comment: @nevilad - I add teste... the size_t return a value like the int = 12. this value like related in problem can be obtain with the code: `int size = sizeof(long double);`

Comment: The value in mingw as an integer (`int size = sizeof(long double);`) is 12, but as long double (`long double size = sizeof(long double);`) it is -2?

Comment: @matzeri - Yes, in mingw included in codeblocks 20.03 is exactly this, but I saw your comment and download separated "MinGW-W64 Online Installer" in this link: [link] (https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/mingw-w64/). With this, the size with int or size_t is printed like 16bits. But, now the values of Size, Min and Max in long double are printed like 0.000000, maybe if i install the version 7 of the mingw  can solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for help me... the solution: download separated "MinGW-W64 Online Installer" (the mingw included in the codeblocks is 32bits because this is printed 12bit) and install the version 7.3.0. (the version 8.1.0 is bugged because this is printed 0.000000 or -0.000000).

Answer (score 0):

Download separated "MinGW-W64 Online Installer" (the mingw included in the codeblocks is 32bits because this is printed 12bit)

and

Install the version 7.3.0. (the version 8.1.0 is bugged because this is printed 0.000000 or -0.000000).

Comment: It's probably a [__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28415046/1983398) issue.