# Issue printing long double in C

Tags: c, windows, gcc, double

For the following snippet of code:

```
  long double foo = 5.32e-5;
  double bar  = foo ;

  printf("%Lf can be written %Le\n", foo, foo);
  printf("%f can be written %e\n", bar , bar);
```

I'm getting this output:

> -1950228512509697500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000 can be written 2.725000e+002
>
> 0.000053 can be written 5.320000e-005

*foo* has been converted to *bar* without issue, this makes me think that the internal representation of the variable is fine, but when I print both these variables *bar* has an accurate representation and *foo* does not.

I believe the formats %Lf and %Le are correct, however I get the same output if I use the lowercase (%lf and %le).  I am using gcc on a window computer.

Comment: I get the same output for both. Using `gcc`

Comment: Somewhere in he back of my mind I remember some issue that C library used for MinGW under Windows systems does not support `long double` type. But I cannot really find a source for that now.

Comment: Does it work with [__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28415046/1983398)?

Comment: MinGW had issues with long double - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66996900/long-double-is-printed-incorrectly-in-codeblocks-using-mingw-long-double

Comment: you also need `long double foo = 5.32e-5L;` to get the full `long double` precision. Note the `L` suffix

Comment: Yes, this was the source of the problem, thanks @phuclv